# Where is a log file with logs from a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running several containers using `docker-compose`. I can see application logs with command `docker-compose logs`. However I would like to access raw log file to send it somewhere for example? Where is it located? I guess it's separate log per each container (inside container?) but where I can find it?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

A container's logs can be found in :

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log
```

(if you use the default log format which is json)

Comment: There are a lot of folders like `004279dd2985037950beeba7e6fe45c10354476d3b82afb68e72dd612b03a8ff`. How to know which folder to look at for a particular container?

Comment: @PraveenSripati the container id for running containers is shown in the first column if you do `docker ps`

Comment: @PraveenSripati write `docker ps`, you'll get all of your available containers along with their IDs. Copy the ID of your desired container, then from `/var/lib/docker/containers/` run `ls | grep <paste the copied docker ID>`. Then you'll see that docker container

Comment: `cd /var/lib/docker/containers/` **-bash: cd: /var/lib/docker/containers/: Permission denied**          `sudo cd /var/lib/docker/containers/` **sudo: cd: command not found**

Comment: @Chris I had to do `docker ps --no-trunc` in order to see the entire id

Comment: @DanZ how come? what would the command output without `no-trunc`?

Comment: @TheLebDev `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                          NAMES` ... `6666980fe505        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest                                "/agent"            15 hours ago        Up 15 hours (healthy)                                  ecs-agent`. I'm on Amazon Linux AMI, connecting with OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1

Comment: For stopped or exited containers try ```docker ps -a```. Take the container id and like other answers grep that id in the /var/lib/docker/containers dir or substitute it into this command ```cat /var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log```

Comment: That is not the case for Linux ubuntu 22.04, at least in my case

Answer (score 122):

You can [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) each container to see where their logs are:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $INSTANCE_ID
```

---

And, in case you were trying to figure out where the logs were to manage their collective size, or adjust parameters of the logging itself you will find the following relevant.

**Fixing the amount of space reserved for the logs**

This is taken from [Request for the ability to clear log history (issue 1083)](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1083#issuecomment-141936600)):

> Docker 1.8 and docker-compose 1.4 there is already exists a method to limit log size using [docker compose log driver](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#log-driver) and log-opt max-size:

```
mycontainer:
  ...
  log_driver: "json-file"
  log_opt:
    # limit logs to 2MB (20 rotations of 100K each)
    max-size: "100k"
    max-file: "20"
```

> In docker compose files of version '2' , the syntax changed a bit:

```
version: '2'
...
mycontainer:
  ...
  logging:
    #limit logs to 200MB (4rotations of 50M each)
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
      max-size: "50m"
      max-file: "4"
```

(note that in both syntaxes, the numbers are expressed as strings, in quotes)

**Possible issue with `docker-compose logs` not terminating**

- [issue 1866](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1866): command `logs` doesn't exit if the container is already stopped

Comment: The short version: docker inspect -f '{{.LogPath}}' $INSTANCE_ID

Comment: from my experience, the `<container-id>.log.*` log files are from the current day. Where does docker log driver store old logs (from previous days), or in case clearing old logs is configured, which configuration is it ?

Comment: @Veverke I do not have access to a Docker environment to check that, but by default, the Docker Compose log driver stores logs in the `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log` file for each container. These logs are rotated daily and compressed, with one file per day kept. The rotated files are named `<container-id>.log.*`, where the `*` represents the date of the log file in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. For example, a log file for a container with ID `abc123` from March 12, 2023, would be named `abc123.log.2023-03-12`.

Answer (score 19):

To see how much space each container's log is taking up, use this:

```
docker ps -qa | xargs docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' | xargs ls -hl
```

(you might need a `sudo` before `ls`).

Comment: I get a permission denied.

Comment: Adding sudo at the end helped: 
`docker ps -qa | xargs docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' | xargs sudo du -hl`

Comment: @Shakedk to fix your permission thing this will be helpful. 

`sudo groupadd docker`
`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

activate the changes to groups:
`newgrp docker`

`sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R`
`sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R`

Answer (score 10):

```
docker inspect <containername> | grep log
```

Comment: `grep "LogPath"` gives the exact line, at least for Docker version 19.03.13.

Comment: Yeah, agreed, but "log" is just memorable

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, the default location is: `C:\ProgramData\Docker\containers\<container-id>-json.log`.

Comment: This is the one when running a local container for development! thanks - it was very hard to find this info

Answer (score 3):

Here is the location for

`Windows 10 + WSL 2  (Ubuntu 20.04), Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61`

Lets say

`DOCKER_ARTIFACTS == \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker`

Location of container logs can be found in

`DOCKER_ARTIFACTS\containers\[Your_container_ID]\[Your_container_ID]-json.log`

Here is an example

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To directly view the logfile in less, I use:

```
docker inspect $1 | grep 'LogPath' | sed -n "s/^.*\(\/var.*\)\",$/\1/p" | xargs sudo less
```

run as `./viewLogs.sh CONTAINERNAME`

Answer (score 1):

As of 8/22/2018, the logs can be found in :

```
/data/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the size of logs per container, you can use this bash command :

```
for cont_id in $(docker ps -aq); do cont_name=$(docker ps | grep $cont_id | awk '{ print $NF }') && cont_size=$(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $cont_id | xargs sudo ls -hl | awk '{ print $5 }') && echo "$cont_name ($cont_id): $cont_size"; done
```

Example output:

```
container_name (6eed984b29da): 13M
elegant_albattani (acd8f73aa31e): 2.3G
```