# docker logs doesn't log detached exec

Tags: node.js, docker

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:4

RUN npm install -g yarn

WORKDIR /app
```

I run `docker run -d` and mount my current working directory as a volume. All the deps are installed by `yarn`. I have a npm script to lint the files.

If I do `docker exec -it [container] npm run lint` it works as expected and I can see all the logs. But if I do `docker exec -itd [container] npm run lint`, it exits immediately which is expected. But I can't see the logs by running `docker logs [container]`. How do I reattach the exec or just see to the logs?

I tried `docker attach [container]` it goes to the repl of nodejs. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Docker look at the log of an exited container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36666246/6309)", you can use [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

```
docker logs -t <container>
```

That will show stdout/stderr (with timestamps because of the `-t` option).

For that last 50 lines of those logs:

```
docker logs -t <container id> | tail -n 50
```

Note: that would work only if npm run lint is run by your container (`docker run <image> npm run lint`)

If your `docker exec` exits immediately, then yes, there would be no logs produces by the container itself.

Comment: I tried the command but it doesn't seem to work. I'm running `docker run -d` and then `docker exec -itd [container]` so I doubt it's because it's running detach mode in detach mode.

Comment: @stevemao Check first that your container did exit with docker ps.

Comment: @stevemao I have edited the answer: `docker logs` would display what the container does, not what `docker exec` does (since `docker exec` has stopped, it does not do anything anymore)

Comment: I'm surprised that there is no way to get the logs. Thanks for the answer :)