# Image is not running on docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to run this [image `quelopes/GeNNet`](https://github.com/quelopes/GeNNet) according to given instructions.

After executing `run` command as I check for image using `docker ps` it shows that there is no image available but If I execute `docker ps -a` the results show that new image was created and exited after a few seconds.
I am using Ubuntu 16.4LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Checks the [logs on that exited container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666348/6309)

As mentioned on [`quelopes/GeNNet`](https://github.com/quelopes/GeNNet), there are prerequisites:

> - The ports must be available/free on the hosting system.
> - The directories dir/Data and dir/Results must exist in the host filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Running a container without the -d flag will show you it's logs as it starts up, these logs will give you the specific reason as to why it failed to run in your case:

```
docker run --rm -p 8787:8787 -p 3838:3838 -p 7474:7474 -v dir/Data:/home/rstudio/Data -v dir/Results/:/home/rstudio/Results quelopes/gennet
```

Would do the trick, note the **--rm** flag, I would use it because I anticipate running the container at least more than once and wouldn't want to create too many of them.