# How to ensure confirmed graceful exit of docker?

Tags: docker

Docker sometimes exists but still keeps running.

Started with :

```
docker run -v $PWD:/host --rm -it Ubuntu_2018
```

After "exit" :
Docker container ls; docker container ls -al

This still shows container running
How to make sure that docker container is gracefully ended?

Using the option `"--rm"` and exiting the docker with "exit" should do the needful. But it still sometimes remains.

After exit, "docker container ls; docker container ls -al" should not show the docker at all

Comment: can you share the output of each of your commands viz `docker run`, `docker container ls` and `docker container ls -al` ?

Comment: `docker container ls -al` also show stopped containers.

Answer (score 1):

> How to ensure confirmed graceful exit of docker?

Not by looking at the `docker container ls -al` output, which as commented shows the stopped containers.

But by looking at:

- the [logs of a stopped container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666348/6309), for an application message stating the stop was graceful (so that depends more on the containerized application, less on Docker itself).
- its Exit status code: `docker inspect -f '{{.State.ExitCode}}' <container SHA>`

For that, see "[Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)" by [Brian DeHamer](https://twitter.com/bdehamer/status/598960095595134976), who reminds us that When you use docker stop or docker kill to signal a container, that signal is sent only to the container process running as PID 1.

See also "[Life and death of a container](https://medium.com/devopsion/life-and-death-of-a-container-146dfc62f808)" from [Luis Herrera Benítez](https://twitter.com/lherrerabenitez) who points out the existence of "`docker inspect --format='{{.State.Health.Status}}' <containerName>`": if it is unhealthy... chances are your subsequent stop might not be graceful.