# How to find Cassandra startup failure cause

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra

I'm trying to run Cassandra in Docker. Previously that was fine (unfortunately I used `latest` image). Now when I run compose with different versions it never succeeds. Sometimes I see in logs that startup compete, sometimes now. Every time it ends up with `cassandra exited with code 137`. I can find no errors in logs. How can I diagnose the problem?

Here's my compose file. I tried to switch between `3.0.24`, `3.11`, `4` and `4.0.1` versions with no luck.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.0.24
    container_name: cassandra
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '9042:9042'
      - '9142:9142'

    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/cassandra-data:/var/lib/cassandra

    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra
    
    networks:
      - default-dev-network

networks:
  default-dev-network:
    external: true
```

UPDATE

Here's a logs example. But it varies from run to run.

```
INFO  16:01:43 Node /172.18.0.5 state jump to NORMAL

INFO  16:01:43 Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...

INFO  16:01:51 No gossip backlog; proceeding

INFO  16:01:51 Netty using native Epoll event loop

INFO  16:01:51 Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork26.142ecbb, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.44.Final.452812a]

INFO  16:01:51 Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...

INFO  16:01:51 Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it

INFO  16:01:51 Startup complete
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666348/11895568

Comment: :) I can see logs but there's no errors there

Comment: What do you get by running `docker inspect`? Most importantly, is `OOMKilled` on true?

Comment: no, it's `false`
```
"State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 137,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-10-23T16:01:36.434508489Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2021-10-23T16:01:54.005601692Z"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was memory or CPU issue. After adding `resources` it runs, but not every time. Playing with CPUs and memory somehow helps but didn't bring reliable result.

Here's full compose file

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.0.24
    container_name: cassandra
    
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits: 
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 2G

    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '9042:9042'
      - '9142:9142'

    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/cassandra-data:/var/lib/cassandra

    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra
    
    networks:
      - default-dev-network

networks:
  default-dev-network:
    external: true
```

Comment: unfortunately this also doesn't work good

Comment: I would say there's not enough RAM to run cassandra. cassandra-env.sh will attempt to default the heap size to one quarter of available RAM. Cassandra 3 would like to have at least 8G in production, for example

Comment: It was long time ago, but I think you're rigth