# Docker compose - server container doesnt start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with docker-compose. It should pull two images - client and server. Everything seems to be fine - images are being pulled and client starts without any issues. The problem exists when it comes to server. Just doesnt start and I cant see any logs. Here's my docker file for server app :

```
FROM docker.io/library/gradle:7.5.1-jdk17 AS builder

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source code to the container's working directory
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle /app/
COPY gradle /app/gradle
COPY src /app/src

# Build the application using a build tool (e.g., Gradle or Maven)
RUN gradle clean build -x test --no-watch-fs

FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/server.jar server.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "server.jar"]
```

and here's my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    image: xxx/react-frontend:latest
    ports:
      - 444:80
    env_file:
      - .env.production



server:
    image: xxx/server:latest
    ports:
      - 8444:8444
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prod
```

after running docker-compose up -d I can see :

```
✔ Network xxx_default     Created                                                                                                  0.1s
 ✔ Container xxx-server-1  Started                                                                                                  1.2s
 ✔ Container xxx-client-1  Started
```

however when I check docker ps there's only one container - client. I cannot check server logs, dont know whats going on. During start I can only see this :

```
xxx-server-1  | Sep 05, 2023 3:38:06 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
xxx-server-1  | INFO: Created user preferences directory.
xxx-server-1  | |  Welcome to JShell -- Version 17.0.8
xxx-server-1  | |  For an introduction type: /help intro
xxx-server-1  |
```

So no info about errors, crash or anything. How can I check whats going on ? Any ideas, please ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666246/docker-look-at-the-log-of-an-exited-container

Comment: Also note that to execute a Java application you can use a JRE base image instead of a JDK. You can use the Temurin's one however the smallest one I know of is https://hub.docker.com/r/pnavato/amazoncorretto-jre/

Comment: just checked but found nothing :/ INFO: Created user preferences directory.
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 17.0.8
|  For an introduction type: /help intro