# Docker multi-container logging cap

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to cap the max size of docker's log files. Each container's log file should max out at 100M. So each container such as the `edge`, `worker`, etc should only be allowed to have a log file that is 100MB.

I tried to insert:

```
log_opt:
    max-size: 100m
```

At the end of my docker-compose.yml file below but i'm getting an error.
Where should I place it?. Also when I place it inside each container definition I'm getting an error. I read the docker docs but no where does it say where exactly to place the option.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - box:/box
  cache:
    image: redis:3.0
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    volumes:
      - ${DATA}/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
  placements-store:
    image: redis:3.0
    command: redis-server ${REDIS_OPTIONS}
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  api:
    image: ruby:2.3
    command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - box:/box
    expose:
      - 3000
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - placements-store
  worker:
    image: ruby:2.3
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/schedule.yml -q default -q high_priority,5 -c 10
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      INSTANCE_TYPE: worker
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - box:/box
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - placements-store
  sidekiq-monitor:
    image: ruby:2.3
    command: bundle exec thin start -R sidekiq.ru -p 9494
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - box:/box
    depends_on:
      - cache
    expose:
      - 9494
  sneakers:
    image: ruby:2.3
    command: bundle exec rails sneakers:run
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      INSTANCE_TYPE: worker
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - box:/box
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - placements-store
      - rabbitmq
  edge:
    image: ruby:2.3
    command: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -p 3000
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://placements-store
      RACK_ENV: development
      BUNDLE_PATH: /box
      RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./edge:/app/
      - box:/box
    depends_on:
      - placements-store
      - rabbitmq
    expose:
      - 3000
  proxy:
    image: openresty/openresty:latest-xenial
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
volumes:
  box:
  # node_modules:
  # bower_components:
  # client_dist:
```

This is what I tried, for example inserting under the `rabbitmq` container:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - box:/box
  cache:
    image: redis:3.0
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    #volumes:
    #  - ${DATA}/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    log_opt:
      max-size: 50m
  placements-store:
    image: redis:3.0
    command: redis-server ${REDIS_OPTIONS}
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

This is the error I get:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for services.rabbitmq: 'log_opt'

Tried to change `log_opt:` with `options:` and got the same error:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for services.rabbitmq: 'options'

Also the docker version is:

```
docker --version && docker-compose --version
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9/1.11.2
docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
```

UPDATE:

Tried using the `logging` option like the doc says (for version 2.0):

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - box:/box
  cache:
    image: redis:3.0
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    #volumes:
    #  - ${DATA}/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
        max-file: 1
  placements-store:
    image: redis:3.0
    command: redis-server ${REDIS_OPTIONS}
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Getting the error:

> ERROR: for rabbitmq  Cannot create container for service rabbitmq:
>   json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string ERROR:
>   Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: while `docker run`has a max_size, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/, I have been unable to find it for docker-compose in the docs at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/logging maybe it was removed, as I find it here https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-specify-max-log-json-file-size-in-docker-compose/20873/3

Comment: @user2915097 yes but the log_opt isn't working.

Comment: in https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-specify-max-log-json-file-size-in-docker-compose/20873/3 there is indentation that you do not have, maybe that is the problem, as often with yaml files

Comment: @user2915097 see my update question.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017329/where-is-a-log-file-with-logs-from-a-container you have to add  `log_driver: "json-file"
log_opt:
  max-size: "100k"
  max-file: "20"` maybe you need to add json-file before log_opt?

Comment: from https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/logging it seems you have to specify a logginf driver, one of `driver: "json-file"
driver: "syslog"
driver: "none"`