# Save logs in Docker volume (write permission for all users on volume)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a [Yii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii) application with **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/conf/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/conf/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
      - .:/var/www/html
```

All is good. Then some functions were added to save logs to folder */var/www/html/data/logs*.

I do my stuff, connect to container and see

```
sudo docker container exec -it php_1 bash

root@16270e4c7275:/app# ls -la /var/www/html/data/logs
total 1
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Jan 12 02:03 . // write permissions to all users for /var/www/html/data/logs
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Dec 30 03:12 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 104 Jan 12 02:03 12-01-2021.log // log is here
```

And then I want to save logs when container will be down. What should I use?

I try to make a volume.

#### File *docker-compose.yml*

```
  php:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/conf/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
      - .:/var/www/html
      - useractionlogs:/var/www/html/data/logs
volumes:
    pgdata:
    useractionlogs:
```

But saving logs failed :-(

In the container I see:

```
sudo docker container exec -it php_1 bash

root@16270e4c7275:/app# ls -la /var/www/html/data/logs
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Jan 12 02:03 . // write permissions are not to all users for /var/www/html/data/logs
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Dec 30 03:12 ..
```

I can do this in the container:

```
chmod go+rw /var/www/html/data/logs
ls -la /var/www/html/data/logs

total 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan 12 02:19 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dec 30 03:12 ..
```

But I should do that after all recreation of the volume.

How can I make logs to be saved correctly? Is there may be another way?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this has to be done through a custom dockerfile based of an [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) base image and by using that you can change the ownership of the content within the */var/www/html* directory to the group (for example, Apache uses the *www-data* user and group) and change the file permissions too.

This way you can follow the security tradition of not using a root as a group permission and also overcome the fact that you have to change permissions manually each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

A correct way to store logs is to send it to stdout. https://12factor.net/logs

> Treat logs as event streams
>
> Logs provide visibility into the behavior of a running app. In
> server-based environments they are commonly written to a file on disk
> (a “logfile”); but this is only an output format.
>
> Logs are the stream of aggregated, time-ordered events collected from
> the output streams of all running processes and backing services. Logs
> in their raw form are typically a text format with one event per line
> (though backtraces from exceptions may span multiple lines). Logs have
> no fixed beginning or end, but flow continuously as long as the app is
> operating.
>
> A twelve-factor app never concerns itself with routing or storage of
> its output stream. It should not attempt to write to or manage
> logfiles. Instead, each running process writes its event stream,
> unbuffered, to stdout. During local development, the developer will
> view this stream in the foreground of their terminal to observe the
> app’s behavior.
>
> In staging or production deploys, each process’ stream will be
> captured by the execution environment, collated together with all
> other streams from the app, and routed to one or more final
> destinations for viewing and long-term archival. These archival
> destinations are not visible to or configurable by the app, and
> instead are completely managed by the execution environment.
> Open-source log routers (such as Logplex and Fluentd) are available
> for this purpose.

https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout/634296#634296

> An amazing recipe is given in the nginx Dockerfile:
>
> forward request and error logs to docker log collector
>
> RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
>
> Simply, the app can continue writing to it as a file, but as a result
> the lines will go to stdout & stderr!

and others

Then work with https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

[Where is a log file with logs from a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017329/where-is-a-log-file-with-logs-from-a-container)