# Why is Loki's Docker Driver Client stopping to log after some time?

Tags: docker, logging, grafana-loki

I want to send logs of my Docker containers to [Grafana Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/). Therefore, I installed Loki's [Docker Driver Client](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/docker-driver/) and started my containers with it. First I can see logs, but after some time I see no more logs.

**Installation**

I installed Loki's Docker Driver Client as a [Docker plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/plugin/) on my Docker Engine (version [20.10.2](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#20102)):

```
$ docker plugin install grafana/loki-docker-driver:master-54d1d3b --alias loki --grant-all-permissions
```

I didn't use the tag `lastest`, because of the bug [Unable to connect to logging plugin in Swarm](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/3189)

**Configuration**

I started my Docker containers with Loki's Docker Driver Client as log driver:

```
$ docker container run
  --log-driver=loki
  --log-opt loki-url="$LOKI_URL"
  --log-opt loki-retries=5
  --log-opt loki-batch-size=400
  --log-opt max-size="10m"
  --log-opt max-file=5
  --detach
  --name $CONTAINER_NAME
  --restart unless-stopped
  $IMAGE:$TAG
```

I also added json-log driver's `max-size` and `max-file` to limit disk space, see [Configuring the Docker Driver](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/docker-driver/configuration/).

**Problem**

First I could see logs in [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) and in command line with [`docker container logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/), but after some time no more logs were shown. If I tried to look into the logs on Docker host and I saw an error:

```
$ docker container logs 75d4b13eb3e8
error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: error getting log reader: LogDriver.ReadLogs: logger does not exist for 75d4b13eb3e8203b9247ecdeb41fdf495cc8fea7dcfc4775fd8261263b1dcd32
```

**Research**

I looked into the directories of the containers (see [Where is a log file with logs from a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017329/where-is-a-log-file-with-logs-from-a-container)), but I couldn't see any log files:

```
$ sudo ls /var/lib/docker/containers/75d4b13eb3e8203b9247ecdeb41fdf495cc8fea7dcfc4775fd8261263b1dcd32
checkpoints  config.v2.json  hostconfig.json  hostname  hosts  mounts  resolv.conf  resolv.conf.hash
```

I also checked the log path (see [Get an instance’s log path](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#get-an-instances-log-path)), but it was empty:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' 75d4b13eb3e8
```

I found container's logs in plugin's directory (see [Loki log driver not storing logs as files on disk, even with keep-file: true](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/2784)), but the log files don't change anymore:

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/docker/plugins/eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288/rootfs/var/log/docker/75d4b13eb3e8203b9247ecdeb41fdf495cc8fea7dcfc4775fd8261263b1dcd32
total 912
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jan 22 12:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root   4096 Jan 22 15:46 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root root 923177 Jan 22 13:34 json.log
```

I looked into Docker daemon's logs (see [Read the logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#read-the-logs)) and found errors and a warning (at the same time logging stopped):

```
$ sudo journalctl -u docker.service | grep eac33cc9913c
[...]
[...]level=error msg="panic: send on closed channel" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error msg="goroutine 153 [running]:" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error msg="main.(*loki).Log(0xc0000c5e00, 0xc0001d81c0, 0xc0000c5e80, 0x0)" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error msg="\t/src/loki/cmd/docker-driver/loki.go:69 +0x2fb" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error msg="main.consumeLog(0xc0002c0480)" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error msg="\t/src/loki/cmd/docker-driver/driver.go:165 +0x4c2" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error msg="created by main.(*driver).StartLogging" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=error msg="\t/src/loki/cmd/docker-driver/driver.go:116 +0xa75" plugin=eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288
[...]level=warning msg="Unable to connect to plugin: /run/docker/plugins/eac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288/loki.sock/LogDriver.StopLogging: Post http://%2Frun%2Fdocker%2Fplugins%2Feac33cc9913ca962a189904392e516dd495d6fd52391fb5af4a34af46b281288%2Floki.sock/LogDriver.StopLogging: EOF, retrying in 1s"
[...]
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue.

My only differences in configuration are that I'm trialing the latest Enterprise Edition (19.03) as it brings [dual logging capability](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/dual-logging/) although this is also supported in the latest CE versions, and I'm using the latest Loki Docker driver client now that the Github issue previously mentioned has been resolved.

I ended up setting the [log-opts properties](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/docker-driver/configuration/#supported-log-opt-options) `no-file` and `keep-file` in docker-compose.yml:

```
logging:
  driver: "loki"
  options:
    loki-url: "http://${LOKI_URL}:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
    loki-batch-size: "400"
    no-file: "false"
    keep-file: "true"
    max-size: "5m"
    max-file: "3"
```

Since making this change I am receiving logs in Loki and can still use docker container logs and docker service logs on my Docker hosts.

`no-file: "false"` tells the driver to continue creating logs on disk and `keep-file: "true"` tells the driver to keep json logs if the container is stopped (by default files are removed).

Note: Originally I was adding these settings to /etc/docker/daemon.json on the host but would still see the `error getting log reader` issue, I had to switch to specifying the log driver per container/swarm service.

Comment: `no-file: "false"` is the default, so I'm using it, too. I didnt set `keep-file: "true"`. I will try it. But then I also have to use `max-file` for clean up log files.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this issue

> First I could see logs in Grafana and in command line with docker container logs, but after some time no more logs were shown.

On **Grafana** please select **Query type: *Range*** not Instant and you will see all the logs for the selected period of time, if exists in loki.

Comment: It is not a problem of using Grafana. There are no logs in Loki anymore.